# Построение списка для графа

Tags: алгоритм, графы, дерево

помогите разобраться по какому принципу построен список для графа.
1-Проснуться;2-Сделать зарядку;3-Принять душ;4-Почистить зубы;5-Одеться;6-Упаковать обед;7-Позавтракать
p.s.Я думал сначала связи 1 уровня- (Почистить зубы,Упаковать обед,Сделать зарядку).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне не совсем ясна суть вопроса. Вас интересует, как из нарисованного вами графа получить нумерованный список? Тогда это [топологическая сортировка](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/topological_sort).

Суть ее проста. Это, по большому счету, небольшая модификация [обхода в глубину](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/dfs). То есть мы от произвольной вершины запускаем алгоритм и смотрим на вершины, которые выходят из рассматриваемой вершины и запускаем алгоритм от них. Как только мы доходим до вершины, из которой не выходит ни одна вершина или все вершины, исходящие из данной посещены (это мы отслеживаем в дополнительном массиве), то мы записываем эту вершину в наш нумерованный список. Это действие повторяется, пока все вершины не будут посещены. Алгоритм рекурсивный, поэтому многие действия, которые я описал, выполнятся как-бы полуавтоматически (например, проверка, посещены ли вершины, исходящие из рассматриваемой). В конце получившийся список необходимо реверсировать.

Если хотите, могу написать упрощенную реализацию, если на e-maxx что-то непонятно. Учтите, что ваш граф должен быть ориентированным и без циклов, чтобы применять топологическую сортировку (хотя, в вашей задаче едва ли может быть иначе).

Что означает список, полученный такой сортировкой? Ну, в вашем случае, это как-бы один из вариантов порядка выполнения всех действий, описанных в графе, с учетом их зависимости друг от друга. Например, в вашем графе четко указано, что можно одеться только после душа, и топологическая сортировка выдаст такую последовательность, что все подобные требования будут учтены. Это значит, что выполняя все действия в полученном порядке, вы не пойдете в душ, будучи одетым, например :) Более же формально, топологическая сортировка нумерует вершины так, чтобы каждое ребро вело из вершины с бОльшим номером в вершину с мЕньшим.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю,что и такая последовательность действительная,пример: 1-7-5-6-2-3-4

Comment: Да, все верно. В такой последовательности все требования учтены. Кстати, топологическая сортировка именно такую и выдаст, скорее всего (т.к. это модификация поиска в глубину, то и номера будут уходить как-бы вглубь, то есть в каждой ветке номера (кроме корня) будут идти в порядке возрастания до самого листа)

Comment: я поэтому и не пойму почему автор книги именно такой вариант предлагает,чем он руководствовался.Поэтому и вопрос задал тут

Comment: Да, мне тоже не совсем ясно. Это будто выполнялось поиском в глубину, но в какие-то моменты алгоритм решал идти в ширину 0_о. Возможно, опечатка. Хотя знаете, это очень похоже на то, что автор захотел дать список не в том порядке, в котором его выдаст сортировка, а в порядке, наиболее приближенном к реальному, но при этом корректному.

Answer (score 2):

Построен дерево, являющееся частным случаем ориентированного ациклического графа (DAG).

Дуги (направленные рёбра) соединяют вершины, которые зависят друг от друга, т.е. действия на одной ветке можно выполнять только в указанном порядке, а между вершинами разных ветвей такой зависимости нет (почистить зубы можно и до зарядки, и после душа).

Все действия можно объединить в один последовательный список с помощью топологической сортировки (вариантов списка может быть много)